# What is the "current" way in GnuCash to "park" the money during a bank transfer?

Tags: money-transfer, gnucash, balance-transfer

I have multiply accounts which I transfer money between them, based on need. Between accounts from different bank family, the transfer takes normally few days.

In this time, the money is already gone from one bank account, but is still not on the other banks account.

Once I download the transfers from the first bank, i get the date which the money was booked. This date doesn't fits the date, which the money was entering the second account.

One i download the transaction of the second bank, since it is maximal few days, then it can detect, that it is the same transfer. Nether the less, adding PayPal account, there is the difference much bigger.

What is the "current" way in GnuCash to "park" the money during a bank transfer?

Answer (score 5):

The first, and simplest, way is just to record the transfer as notionally all happening on the same day.  That is, if you record money leaving your account at Bank A on the first day of the month, you record it going straight into your account at Bank B on the same day - even though Bank B might not report the arrival of the money until the 4th or 5th day of the month.

When you go to reconcile your account at Bank B with the bank statement in hand, you will know that your GnuCash record of a funds transfer on the 1st represents the same transfer that Bank B tells you happened on the 4th, so there is no difficulty in reconciling your accounts.  Clearly, you can't spend the money from Bank B until the bank tells you that it's arrived, but no accounting treatment is going to change that.

An alternative, if you really must have a record in GnuCash of your Bank B account that matches the bank's records for *every single day*, is to create a notional "funds in transit" account - which would be an **Asset** type account, but not attached to any particular bank.  When you initiate a bank-to-bank transfer, show the money leaving Account A and moving into "funds in transit".  A few days later, when you know that the money has turned up at Bank B, you can record in GnuCash that money has moved from the "funds in transit" account into Account B.  I'm not sure that you'll achieve any substantial gains from this approach, though.

Comment: In my accounts I call this 'funds in transit' account "Limbo Land". The funds still exist, but are... in limbo... <spooky music>